# IE on Windows Phone triggers onerror when loading an image in Javascript

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8.1, dom-events, internet-explorer-11

When I run below Javascript, all browsers including all versions of IE on desktop trigger the `onload` handler, but IE on Windows Phone 8.1 triggers `onerror`. Is this a bug? And if so is there a good fix for it?

```
var image = new Image();

image.onload = function(){
    alert('onload');
};

image.onerror = function(){
    alert('error');
};

image.src = 'http://youtube.com/favicon.ico';
```

Link to test page:
http://sandbox.saeidmohadjer.com/test_winphone_img_onerror.html

Comment: Could it be that the .ico is not supported? Did you try a different format?

Comment: Indeed it seems to be related to .ico!

Comment: Same problem here. I was trying to append a script to the head, thought it was a crossbrowser thing but it's not. Did you find a solution meanwhile?